# Executing JAR file with a file argument in Perl

Tags: java, perl, jar

I'm still learning Perl at the moment and have been trying to get a Perl script working.

This is a simple script that executes a Java JAR file with a text file as an input parameter as its configuration file.

For example if I were to execute the jar normally in the commandline:

```
java -jar myfile.jar sometextfile.txt
```

I want to do this in Perl. So far, I have:

```
open(INPUT, "<$ARGV[0]");

my @args = ("java", "-jar", "nyfile.jar", INPUT);
system(@args);

close(INPUT);
```

The script doesn't seem to pass the input file when it is executed. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't open the file in Perl, just pass the file name (as an argument) to Java:

```
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "nyfile.jar", $ARGV[0]);
```